# Displaying a set of radio buttons

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a set of radio buttons that I am displaying currently, how can I set the currently selected radio button correct?

Note:  I have jquery that will detect a click on a radio button and then post back the information to update the database

I'm not sure this is the cleanest way but I am currently doing the following:

```
<% Users.each do |user| %>
  <% User.statuses.each do |k,v| %>
   <input type=radio value="<%= k %> class="" id="user-<%= user.id %>" name="user[<%= user.id %>]" data-status="<%= v %>"> <%= k %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

How can I set the checked value for the radio button?

I have the current value with <%= user.status %>

I have to do soemthign like:

```
if user.status == v
   puts "checked"
```

But not sure how to do that with inline view script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`radio_button_tag`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/radio_button_tag) helper like:

```
<% Users.each do |user| %>
  <% User.statuses.each do |k,v| %>
   <%= 
     radio_button_tag(
       "user[#{user.id}]",
       k,
       user.status == v,
       class: "",
       id: dom_id(user),
       data: { status: v }
     )
   %> <%= k %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: is a radio button not a checkbox?